# Android, startActivityForResult with arguments (Intent, Int), gives type mismatch error

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

Trying to turn bluetooth on, I used startActivityForResult with arguments (Intent, Int), as follows.

```
val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT : Int = 1;

if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
    val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
```

I get a type mismatch error for both arguments. "Required Activity - found Intent" for the first argument, "Required Intent - found Int" for the second argument. According to documentation the arguments should be (Intent, Int) as used in the code. I have imported the only suggestion in android studio

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult
```

Programming with kotlin, compose. Can somebody help me here?

EDIT: Looks like there are (at least) two different startActivityForResult functions. Android studio (in my project) proposes only the ActivityCompat case for import. I cannot figure out how to import the right one. According to the answers so far, the startActivityForResult that is working with that code is in one of the packages

```
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import android.app.Activity
```

But android studio ignores them.

Comment: Are you actually in an Activity class? That's the only place you can run that code.

Comment: No, I am in a composable function called from a NavHostController. I am using jetpack compose.

Comment: But all this is hapening inside the MainActivity I guess, the starting point of the app.

Comment: If you're in a composable, you shouldn't be using `startActivityForResult` at all. Why aren't you using the [Compose integrations specific for Activity Results](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#activity_result)?

Comment: I have no idea how to pass intent "Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)" in rememberLauncherForActivityResult() API or any other compose activity results function , as indicated in the https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/setup . Or is there some other way for compose and rememberLauncherForActivityResult() - I mean not passing intent. My goal is to enable bluetooth.

Comment: Did you see the very first link in that section that link to the [Activity Result documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) or read the last line that links to how you can create a [custom contract](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom) to handle any Intent?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am not sure I understand what you mean. I had a close look at Activity Result documentation and custom contact creation as in your links. It seems a lot complicated for me and I cannot figure out how it could be used in my case, for enabling bluetooth. Could you be more specific please? With some example code maybe or some advices that could address the specific problem;

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is on your import.

The `startActivityForResult` you are using is this

```
public static void startActivityForResult(
        @NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Intent intent,
        int requestCode, @Nullable Bundle options) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        Api16Impl.startActivityForResult(activity, intent, requestCode, options);
    } else {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}
```

And you should be using this one from `import android.app.Activity`

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Comment: What should I import then? import android.app.Activity has no startActivityForResult() function

Comment: What are you using? ComponentActivity or AppCompatActivity?

Comment: I tried - import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity - , it ignores it.

Comment: By "ignores it", i mean that the startActivityForResult is displayed in red as unresolved reference. When alt+enter android studio proposes "import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForRwsult" that leads to the wrong startActivityForResult.

Comment: The same with android.app.Activity . It ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
```

It will already imported if you are using Compose.

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
```

In the build.gradle file try implementing dependency activity-compose version 1.7.2, it was working for me.

Comment: I was using "import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity" , with  dependency "... activity-compose: 1.8.2". I downgraded to 1.7.2 as you suggest but nothing changed. It ignores " import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity". When alt+enter to the red "startActivityForResult", Android studio proposes "import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompact.startActivityForResult" that leads to the wrong startActivityForResult.